# Unity Container for holding User Session objects MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm buold MVC4 C# website.
I have base controller with constructor

```
public BaseController(IUnityContainer container, SessionContext context)
```

The problem is that container is shared globally and when i try to resolve or register objects they are shared through sessions. On the other hand SessionContext (parameter) comes only is unique to user session. **I want container to be unique for user sessions (to be able resolve unique objects for user sessions), but i don't know how to implement it**.
I have UnityControllerFactory as follows:

```
public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
     private IUnityContainer container;

     public UnityControllerFactory(IUnityContainer container){
         this.container = container;
         this.RegisterTypes();
      }

     protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)
     {
         if (controllerType != null)
         {
            return this.container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
         }
         return null;
     }

     private void RegisterTypes(){
             container.RegisterType<SessionContext>(new UnityPerSessionLifetimeManager("private.SessionContext"));                    
             container.RegisterType<DataService>(new UnityPerSessionLifetimeManager("private.Service"));    
     }
}
```

and lifetime manager

```
public class UnityPerSessionLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager
    {
        private string sessionKey;

        public UnityPerSessionLifetimeManager(string sessionKey)
        {
            this.sessionKey = sessionKey;
        }

        public override object GetValue()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[this.sessionKey];
        }

        public override void RemoveValue()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(this.sessionKey);
        }

        public override void SetValue(object newValue)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[this.sessionKey] = newValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you make sure `GetValue()` doesn't return `null` for `sessionKey = "private.Service"`?

Comment: I think your question/concern needs better explaination.. in particular, explain the 'on the other hand' remark using some actually implementation code and a given scenerio.. the way I'm reading it.. you're stating that the global container resolves the types from the session variables already..

Comment: As a side note, I don't really see a benefit to registering types in your current manner. I would do `container.RegisterType<ISessionContext, SessionContext>` which resolves the interface to an instance of SessionContext (constructed with either no parameters OR parameters that have been previously registered in the unity container - thus those parameters are resolved when SessionContext is resolved)..

Comment: In this manner, I you're that much closer to exposing only your interfaces to your presentation tier/layer (or app).. of course, to do that.. you should put unity into it's own class library project that imports web namespaces..  your app, should not have to know what types are actually being resolved to.. it just needs to know how to interface with them, right?